# Failure to trigger eventlistener on button in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a frontend developer course (Scrimba module 3 solo project) and I came over a problem where a button will not fire its click event listener. As one can see in the provided screenshot, there is indeed an event listener on the inspected element but it won't fire when any of the heart buttons are clicked.

Is there something I am missing using `querySelectorAll`? I have tried selecting it with `getElementById` individually and `getElementByClass` collectively but same issue. I tried using `data="${post.id}"` in a conditional but still not working.

Any help with this code is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of my debugger verifying the eventilistener is there]

```
import endorsementsPostsData from './data.js'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'https://jspm.dev/uuid';

const inputField = document.getElementById('input-field')
const inputFieldFrom = document.getElementById('input-field-from')
const inputFieldTo = document.getElementById('input-field-to')
const publishButton = document.getElementById('publish-button')
const endorsementsContainer = document.getElementById('endorsements-container')
const heartsButtons = document.querySelectorAll('heart-buttons')

renderPosts(endorsementsPostsData)
 
function renderPosts(data){
    data.forEach((post)=>{
        endorsementsContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="endorsment-post" id="${post.id}">
            <h4>To ${post.reciever}</h4>
            <p>${post.message}</p>
            <div class="endorsement-post-footer">                       
                <h4>${post.sender}</h4>
                <div class="likes-container"> 
                    <button class="heart-buttons" id="${post.id}" data="${post.id}">❤</button>
                    <span class="likes-span">${post.hearts}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
    })
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if(e.target === publishButton){
        let newEndorsement = [{    
        'id': uuidv4(),
        'reciever': `${inputFieldTo.value}`,
        'sender': `${inputFieldFrom.value}`,
        'message': `${inputField.value}`,
        'isLiked': false,
        'hearts': 0,}]
        
        renderPosts(newEndorsement)
    }

    if(e.target === heartsButtons){
        console.log('clicked')
    }
})
```

Comment: You select the elements before they exist `const heartsButtons = ...` and then you render them `renderPosts(endorsementsPostsData)`. It is like looking for a toilet before you walk into the bathroom. You are most likely not going to find one. Now if the code would work, the check to see if you clicked on something would not match an html collection.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the previous inacurate explanation, use this block of code on the eventListener, the goal is to test if you are getting the right class.
pls make the test and give me a feedback

```js
document.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.className.includes("heart-buttons")) {
      console.log('❤︎');
      //console.log(event.target.dataset);
      //console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data'));
    } else {
      console.log(`something else (${target.tagName})`);
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<button class="heart-buttons">❤︎</button>
<button class="broken-heart-buttons">︎</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Where should I use template strings? I tried your code snippet but still the eventlistener won't fire.

Comment: the problem may be in the class the const heartsButtons is equal to the a dom element, and not to the string "heart-buttons" which is the class name, test that new block of code and see if you are getting the right class.

Comment: That's interesting. The first console.log gives a DOMTokenList in console: 

`DOMTokenList ['heart-buttons', value: 'heart-buttons']
0
: 
"heart-buttons"
length
: 
1
value
: 
"heart-buttons"
[[Prototype]]
: 
DOMTokenList`
But the second console.log for clicks does not fire.

Comment: awesome !Now you are going to work with that array and use the method classList.includes("heart-buttons") or className.includes("heart-buttons")... to know more about it search includes on mdn documentation

Comment: Thanks! I need to get it to match the id of the clicked heart. Will dig into this :) Again thanks alot!

Comment: I have corrected your original snippet since it was first mistakenly comparing classList with string literal and had prematurely finished listener function body. Used the `el.className === 'sth`' for demonstrative purposes. Normally you would either use `el.className === 'exactClass'` or `el.classList.contains('someClass')` or `el.matches('.someClass')`. Current version with `el.className.includes('someClass')` is not optimal either, since it would give false (unexpected) positives for e.g. `<el class="awesomeClass">`

Comment: Try one of the console.logs inside the comments and give-me a feedback. Is a test, to see if we can reach the correct data atribute. Tip: when working with data attributes, i recommend to give more meaningful names e.g data-post-id.